# Find the second derivative of the given function

Tags: derivatives

> If $$x=a(\cos \theta + \theta \sin \theta) $$$$ y=a(\sin \theta- \theta \cos \theta) $$ prove that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{\sec^3 \theta}{a \theta}$$

Can you solve this for me?

I tried finding $\frac{dy}{dx} $ by dividing $\frac{dy}{dt} $ by $\frac{dx}{dt} $ but failed to get the required answer

$$\frac{\frac{d}{d \theta} \frac{ \cos \theta + \theta \sin \theta}{\theta \cos \theta - \sin \theta}}{\frac{dx}{d \theta}}=\frac{1+\theta^2}{a(\theta \cos \theta- \sin \theta)}$$
I am stuck here

Please offer your assistance. :)

Comment: Question is clearly wrong where did you get this from. You will not have "a" in the final answer that leads me to believe question is wrong where did you get question what's the source???

Comment: It is from a reputed book. I have many similar questions with answers containing a which will cancel out in the method we followed

Comment: I think that there is some other way to find it

Comment: i am 100% certain there is no a in the answer think of it from a graph point of view the "a" will have no influence on second derivative let alone the first derivative.

Comment: can you tell me book name and page number

Comment: The answer specified by the OP is definetely correct and can be derived using the hint I gave in the answers below.

Comment: @Jam From the graph point of view, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. Scaling the graph by a factor of $a$ will definitely affect the second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$y_t=at\sin t,~~x_t=at\cos t,~~ y'=\frac{y_t}{x_t}=\tan t,t\neq (2k+1)\pi/2,~~y''=\frac{\sec^2 t}{x_t}$$

Comment: "Spot on" Babak! +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\large\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{dy}{dx})\times\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{dy}{dx})}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$

And of course: $\large\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$

Comment: Very nice hints. +1

Comment: can someone post the answer. I still couldnt reach the answer

Comment: @chndn -- It would be better if you posted the work you have done so far in trying to get to the answer so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake.

Comment: okay i am gonna edit it

Comment: @chndn -- can you please show how you got your values for $dy/d\theta$ and $dx/d\theta$?